# Twilio Video - Call participant to join video call

Tags: android, ios, video, twilio

I'm kinda new to `Twilio`.

I'm having trouble trying to get the participant to join a video call (room) by notifying him via a phone call.

All I know is when Participant 'A' creates a room 'TestRoomName' to have a one-to-one video call with Participant 'B', 'B' must know what the room name is to connect or otherwise be notified that he has to join.

But is there a way to implement in such a way that 'B' gets a call once 'A' creates a room, and upon B's answer, he joins the room?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Programmable Video](http://twilio.com/docs/api/video) doesn't actually include a mechanism for inviting users to rooms, only to make rooms that are available to those users only.

You need to build your own notification method to connect the users. I'd recommend checking out [Twilio Notify](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify) for performing cross platform notifications. Then, when you create the room you can also trigger a notification to the other user and send the name of the room in the notification's data, so that when they react to the notification they can join the room.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Is using Twilio Notify or Firebase Cloud Messaging still the way to go for building calling screen feature?

Comment: Hey @SudhirKhanger, not sure what you mean by "building calling screen feature". Can you explain a bit more what you want to do?

Comment: oh sorry about that. I meant to say a screen or notification which shows that the other person is waiting in the room. So similar to how video call apps work. Video call apps like Duo, WhatsApp, etc. open an Activity/Screen and lets user answer or decline the call. I would send a Twilio Notification or FCM notification which a user can respond to join or decline to join a room. Not sure how reliable these are but they seem to be the best possible way to achieve the goal.

Comment: Yes, that is still the best way. Twilio Notify uses FCM and APNS under the hood, but makes them available by the one API.

Comment: As of October 24, 2022, Twilio Notify is no longer for sale to new customers and it will reach end of life on October 23rd 2023 for existing customers.